# Как распознать поворот фотографии на 90 град. средствами Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как распознать средствами Javascript поворот на 90 град. файла фотографии, загруженного в input?

HTML

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file">
</form>
```

JS

```
$('input').on("change", function (event, files) {
    if (this.files[0]) {
        var fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = function (event, files) {
            var rotation = .....;
            if(rotation=='90') return true;
            else return false;
        };
    }
    return false;
 });
```

Comment: А где у фотографии верх?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584794/accessing-jpeg-exif-rotation-data-in-javascript-on-the-client-side Конечно надо понимать, что далеко не все камеры знают свое положение и пишут соответствующую EXIF информацию

Comment: А кроме exif по каким параметрам можно определить?